# jQuery issue with updating HTML from ajax call to PHP page.

Tags: php, jquery

So I'm having an issue getting the correct count of array elements in a PHP $_SESSION array. I'm using $_SESSION['user']['list'] to store the unique identifiers of items a user picked from a php page. I'm using jquery and a PHP page to handle that on click. This part works flawlessly. A user clicks a button and the buttons' unique identifier is added to $_SESSION['user']['list'].

My issue is that I'm trying to dynamically update the count of the list on the menu using jquery. This is what **does not** work flawlessly. Sometimes the count updates with the correct number. Sometimes it does not. I'm thinking it may be a caching issue but I thought using .post took care of caching issues. I've also tried $.ajax with cache: false. I've spent more time than I'd like to admit on this specific problem and it's gnawing at me.

So here is the code which should update the html in the menu:

```
$.post("listme.php").done(function(data){$('#list_count').html(data);});
```

In the above I tried to use `success` as well but came out with the same issues.

Now listme.php works fine, I've tested it many times and it gives the correct number on page load and even though the item count on the menu does not update correctly on click, it does work fine on subsequent page load. So I know it is working (famous last word here). listme.php just prints out the count() of $_SESSION['user']['list']. I can see the response in the console and it's just plain wrong. I click add, it adds it to the Session but the number in `#list_count` says 0. If I reload the page the count says 1. If I add more, it might skip one or two adds, sometimes it adds one, sometimes it doesn't. The Session is always updated though, and if I refresh the page, the count is correct.

I feel like it has to be some sort of caching issue.

So here's the caching bit in my .htaccess:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2 year"

</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong in either the jquery code or my .htaccess?

Comment: There is nothing magical going on. The PHP is *possibly* getting cached but it's unlikely. [See this image for a cached resource](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uJKew.png). If you have some low-end hosting provider then they could be doing some sort of PHP-level caching which you have no control over but that's a discussion for a different day. My gut instinct tells me that there is some issue with the logic in your PHP script and it is outputting the wrong count of items. Do a simple test and see what you get...

Comment: Keep all of your jQuery and .htaccess the same and try this for **listme.php**: `<?php session_start(); if(!isset($_SESSION['count'])){$_SESSION['count'] = 0;} $_SESSION['count']++; echo $_SESSION['count'];`

Comment: Data Size 
Expires 
Sun Feb 07 2106 01:28:15 GMT-0500 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Fetch Count 
2
Last Fetched 
Wed Aug 10 2016 14:43:33 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)
Last Modified 
Wed Dec 31 1969 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Comment: There is your issue; `Expires Sun Feb 07 2106`

Comment: Try putting `header('Expires: Mon Aug 01 2016 01:28:15 GMT');` at the top of your **listme.php** file.

Comment: I just did that and it did not have any effect.

Comment: So it retained the same expiration date?

Comment: Data Size 
Expires 
Sun Feb 07 2106 01:28:15 GMT-0500 (Eastern Daylight Time) still. Very interesting. I have no idea where this would be set at

Comment: Try adding `ExpiresByType text/html "access minus 1 year"` to your .htaccess file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120628/discussion-between-mmundiff-and-monkeyzeus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our discussion in chat the ultimate solution was to update the session count and output the count in one shot.

Something which might or might not have helped was making sure that the page was not getting cached:

```
header('Expires: Mon Aug 01 2016 01:28:15 GMT');
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to update the count in the session and then use a separate call to update the html with the count on the same php script. For whatever reason calling the same script (via jquery) twice in very fast succession caused issues. I'm still not sure if it was a caching issue or jQuery trying to mitigate possible server abuse. Either way @MonkeyZeus suggested to do the update and return the count back in the same call and this was the answer to my issue. Many thanks to @MonkeyZeus!

Comment: @mmundiff I just wanted to let you know that the reason why fast succession was causing issues for you is because AJAX is asynchronous so it is quite possible that Request1 leaves the web browser and is followed by Request2. For whatever reason (slow network, routing, server slowness), Request2 comes back to the browser first so the `success()` block is executed and then Request1 comes back as well and its `success()` block is executed as well. The problem is though, Request1 has old data and it happens so fast. I have a feeling that caching was never an issue in your case.